# Can anyone explain one claim about the infinity norm?

Tags: measure-theory

Define $||f||_\infty $ as the infimum of the essential upper bounds for f.

> For each natural number n, there is a subset $E_n$ such that $|f|
> \leq||f||_\infty + \frac{1}{n}$ on $E - E_n$ and $m(E_n)=0$.

Why is this true?

Comment: That's going to depend on your definitions...to me that is a trivial consequence of the definition of the infinity norm, which to me is something like $\inf_{A \subset X : m(A) = 0} \sup_{x \in X \setminus A} |f(x)|$.

Comment: Added definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $||f||_\infty$ is the infimum of essential upper bounds, then anything above it is an essential upper bound. Hence $||f||_\infty+1/n$ is an essential upper bound, so $f>||f||_\infty+1/n$ on a set of measure zero. Call that set $E_n$. Thus $f\leq||f||_\infty+1/n$ on $E-E_n$ and $m(E_n)=0$.